# While loop doesn't loop in java

Tags: java

My while loop in Java doesn't loop even though the boolean is still false (I think?).

If I remove all the "**mysqlStatus = true**" it still doesn't want to loop. I don't really understand how that is possible as I never switch the boolean to "true".

It's probably something stupid though so thanks in advance for the help :).

The loop:

```
    Connection conn;
    Boolean mysqlStatus = false;

    while(mysqlStatus.equals(false)) {

        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conTest = DriverManager.getConnection(host + dbName, username, password);
            mysqlStatus = true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // server offline

            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Database offline");
            alert.setHeaderText("De MySQL database server is offline");
            alert.setContentText("Start de server en probeer opnieuw.");

            ButtonType buttonTypeOne = new ButtonType("Opnieuw controleren");
            ButtonType buttonTypeCancel = new ButtonType("Exit", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);

            alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(buttonTypeOne, buttonTypeCancel);

            Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
            if (result.get() == buttonTypeOne){
                mysqlStatus = false;
                alert.close();
            } else {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mysqlStatus = false;
            ExceptionDialog cexD = new ExceptionDialog();
            cexD.setStrError("Er is een onverwachte fout opgetreden.");
            cexD.setException(e);
        } finally {
            try {
                conTest.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                mysqlStatus = false;
                ExceptionDialog cexD = new ExceptionDialog();
                cexD.setStrError("Er is een onverwachte fout opgetreden.");
                cexD.setException(e);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't do

```
mysqlStatus.equals(false)
```

in java. Not sure what that will do.

You need to do

```
(!mysqlStatus)
```

for checking conditions.

Comment: Changed it and it still doesn't loop.

Comment: @Niell How do you know it does not loop? Do not forget that you put your variable to `true` within the try clause.

Comment: Did you test that though? It's not normal, but it should still work.

Comment: That is other problem @Niell

Comment: I removed all the code where I put it to true before I tested it. I'm running this code in a constructor of an object if it matters?

Answer (score 0):

From [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/boolean_equals.htm):

> The **java.lang.Boolean.equals(Object obj)** returns `true` if and only if
>   the argument is not `null` and is a `Boolean` object that represents the
>   same boolean value as this object.

now `false` is a primitive `boolean` literal (which is either `true` or `false` and not `Boolean` object. `Boolean` object can be `true`, `false`, or `NULL`)

So, what happen when you do:

```
mysqlStatus.equals(false)
```

is you compare a `Boolean` object `mysqlStatus` with `boolean` primitive literal `false` (and not `Boolean` object with `false` value) and therefore it *always* returns `false` (because `mysqlStatus` is not the same `Boolean` object as `false`) and as a result you never enter the `while` loop.

Do this to compare if `mysqlStatus` is `false` with `Boolean` object:

```
while(Boolean.FALSE.equals(mysqlStatus)) //also handle NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Any Exception besides an SQLException like ClassNotFoundException will be catched by Exception and loop endlessly.
There call break or such.

Boolean is the Object wrapper class for the primitive type boolean.

```
boolean mysqlStatusVastgesteld = false;

while (!mysqlStatusVastgesteld) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by making a function that checks the status.

```
    public Boolean checkStatus() {

        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            Connection conTest = DriverManager.getConnection(host + dbName, username, password);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // server offline
            return false;
        }

    }
```

I also made a while loop that runs this function until it returns true. If it returns false a dialog appears and asks to retry or exit.

All works now. This was a weird issue but thanks everyone for trying to help! There were multiple mistakes in my code.